# Can you use the name of a turtle in the parameters of a variable?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

```py
import turtle as trtl
def position(hold):
  hold.forward(200)

position('trtl')
```

I'm trying to make a program which has multiple turtles use a similar function between all of them, is something like what is shown in the image possible?

Comment: Enough information to answer a question needs to be included **in the body of the question itself** to comply with [mre] rules. Code should not be in screenshots; see [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: ...now that that's fixed -- the immediate problem is that if you run `import turtle as trtl1; import turtle as trtl2`, both `trtl1` and `trtl2` are _the same turtle_; they're just references to the same entry in the module cache, so it's not "multiple turtles" at all in the first place.

Comment: Mind, the `turtle` module _does_ let you instantiate separate turtles, but (1) you need to actually do that; and (2) why would you pass the names and not the objects?

Comment: (to be clear, you _can_ track them in such a way as to pass them by name, but it makes your code more complex and somewhat slower; our scope is limited to _practical_, answerable questions, so I'm asking what practical value you expect to get out of passing a string rather than a direct reference to the object)

Comment: Very likely an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/233676#233676). Just pass `turtle` instances into the function. It's _possible_ to do this, but what problem are you trying to solve with it? There's almost definitely a better design you can apply here.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to refer to things by name, store them in a dict; use the name as keys.

```
import turtle

turtles = {
  "one": turtle.Turtle(),
  "two": turtle.Turtle(),
}

def position(turtle_name):
  return turtles[turtle_name].forward(200)

position('one')
```

...but it's unclear why you'd do that at all instead of...

```
import turtle as turtle_mod

turtle_one = turtle_mod.Turtle()
turtle_two = turtle_mod.Turtle()

def position(turtle):
  return turtle.forward(200)

position(turtle_one)
```

Comment: This plays too much into OP's undesirable design misunderstanding. Better to pass the instances themselves in, almost certainly. A list of turtles that can be indexed `[0]`, `[1]`, `[2]` seems much better than magic string literal names, and even if they should be accessible in a dict, I'd prefer `position(turtles["one"])` so that the function isn't dependent on a global structure existing. Lots of code smell here, `position` is a poor func name (noun, not verb), etc.